# Flutter Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

I am trying to fetch data from API and store the data in a list so that I can use the listin my code but it gives an error of **Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0**

Below is the code

```
class Services {
  final String apiKey = '*Hidden*';
  static const int numberOfFood = 50;
  List<String> foodNameList = [];
  getRandomBreakfast() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(
          'https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/random?apiKey=$apiKey&number=$numberOfFood&tags=breakfast?'),
    );
    dynamic foodData = response.body;
    Map data = json.decode(foodData);
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFood; i++) {
      String foodName = (data['recipes'][i]['title']);
      foodNameList.add(foodName);
    }
  }
}
```

I want to use it in the below GridView builder

```
GridView.builder(
                  itemCount: Services.numberOfFood,
                  gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                    childAspectRatio: 0.7,
                  ),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return FoodContainer(
                        foodLabel: Services().foodNameList[index]);
                  },
                ),
```

Comment: itemCount: Services. foodNameList.length

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your data is empty, try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFood; i++) {
  if ((data['recipes'] as List).isNotEmpty) {
    String foodName = (data['recipes'][i]['title']);
    foodNameList.add(foodName);
  } else {
    print('Empty')
  }
}
```